# Truncated gaussian integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I wish to calculate $$\int_0^\infty \int_{-x}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt {2\pi}} \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\, dy\, dx = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt {2\pi}} \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\, dy\, dx + \int_0^\infty \int_{-x}^0 \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt {2\pi}} \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\, dy\, dx $$

$$= \frac{1}{4} + \int_0^\infty \int_{-x}^0 \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt {2\pi}} \frac{e^{-y^2/2}}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\, dy\, dx. $$

However, I'm not sure how to evaluate the second term. Since the inner integral is truncated, I don't know if converting to polar coordinates will help.

Comment: The last double integral is clearly (a matter of symmetry) $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{4\pi} \left(\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2}\textrm{d}x\right)^2.$$

Comment: why don't you let $u=-y$ so $I=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{x}{e^{-x^2/2}.e^{-u^2/2}du dx}$ By definition $\int_{0}^{x}{f(t)dt}=\int{f(x)dx}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By symmetry, note that:
$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^x f(x,y)\,dy\,dx = \int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty f(x,y)\,dx \,dy=\int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty f(y,x)\,dy\,dx,$$
so if $f$ is symmetric:
$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^x f(x,y)\,dy\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f(x,y)\,dy\,dx.$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

If we don't want to go deep into the details, I would consider the question as the training excercise for two classical methods:

1) integration by parts,

2) use of the property of the CDF of a standard normal distribution (denote it by $\Phi(x)$) that $\Phi(-x)=1-\Phi(x)$ for any $x$.

Let $\phi(x)=\Phi'(x)$. Since $\Phi(\infty)=1$, 
then what we are interested in is the value of
$$
\int_0^\infty dx
\phi(x)
\int_{-x}^\infty d\Phi(y)
=
\int_0^\infty dx
\phi(x)
(1-\Phi(-x))
$$

Since $\Phi(-x)=1-\Phi(x)$ we have 
$$
\int_0^\infty dx
\phi(x)
\int_{-x}^\infty d\Phi(y)
=
\int_0^\infty dx
\phi(x)
\Phi(x).
$$

The integral on the right is computed using the method 1),
which yields the required solution $0.375$.